# Informing an ajax call that the session has timed-out or user needs to re-authenticate

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have nailed down a challenge for me which was the ability to log and continue/Inform a user about server exceptions when the request is ajax. Using the `OnException` in the base controller and looking for the request being ajax I can return a customized "...uhoh" view to be rendered.

Now, I am battling the not authenticated portion of stuff. I am struggling with this modified code I was thinking of using in place of the `[Authorize]` attribute in my base classes.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class AjaxAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult{Data = new{NotAuthenticated=1}, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently, there are a few areas where this could return NotAuthenticatedas data to the Ajax calls in the client. Am I going about this the right way? Just located the main flows that end in an Ajax.

```
if(returnData.NotAuthenticated){
    if (that.onNotAuthenticated != null)
       that.onNotAuthenticated();
    else
      _loadView(viewElement, "Request requires authorization. Please login again.");
} else
      _loadView(viewElement, returnData);
}
```

However, I am using the Kendo complete library and possibly others. Is there a better "Global" way to handle session timeouts or auth redirects when triggered via an Ajax call?

Please help!

Comment: One advice on asking your questions, keep it simple and short with only required information. I just read your last paragraph :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [`Global Ajax Event Handlers`](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) meets your needs. For example following code sets a global error handler which will redirect user to login page if her session is timeout.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    if (jqxhr.status == 401 || jqxhr.statusText == "Unauthorized") {
        window.location.href = '/login';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, do you by chance know off the top of your head if this replaces the local handlers or runs in conjunction before or after?

Comment: @lrb: You're welcome. AFAIK, It doesn't replace any _local handlers_, it runs in conjunction  with them. I have used it in many of our web apps.